# libusb for Android using open2(, int fd)

Tags: android, c, libusb

I compiled the modified version of libusb to be used in Android devices from

https://github.com/martinmarinov/rtl_tcp_andro-/blob/master/jni/libusb-andro/README

Is there any example on how to use this particular function in a C program?

1. What headers need to be included in order for this library to work.
2. Any examples on how to use  open2(, int fd)  in a C program

Answer (score 2):

This is no new library. Only a modified version of libusb. So, all the libusb commands are applicable here. The only difference would be libusb_open2 which you would have to use in stead of libusb_open. From the libusb/libusb.h file, the prototype of libusb_open2 is visible.

```
int LIBUSB_CALL libusb_open2(libusb_device *dev, libusb_device_handle **handle, int fd);
```

Now, for using libusb on android, the steps would be.

1. First get permissions for the USB device you are interested in. The details are given here : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host.html
2. Then extract the file descriptor of the USB device using the method [getFileDescriptor()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/usb/UsbDeviceConnection.html#getFileDescriptor%28%29)
3. Use this file descriptor open connection to the usb device. That is make a libusb_device.

Now you can use this libusb_device to do all the stuff that can be done on computer using libusb. There are plenty of examples given on the [libusb website](http://www.libusb.org/).

For other queries you can hangout on #libusb on freenode.
For specific examples, go through the documentation. Try on your own. And if stuck somewhere ask here. Do no expect spoonfeeding.