# Android L | libusb_init returns LIBUSB_ERROR_OTHER (-99)

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-5.0-lollipop, libusb

I trying to use `libusb` on not rooted Nexus 5 as advised in [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24243605/902217) (by transferring usb file descriptor from java to native side).

My application ask permission via `UsbManager.requestPermission` and then run native method that call `libusb_init` to create `libusb_context`.

But `libusb_init` returns `LIBUSB_ERROR_OTHER` code (-99). After digging in the code I see why this happening. libusb reports `'could not find usbfs'` because `opendir("/dev/bus/usb")` returns `0`.

Also from `adb shell` I can't perform `ls /dev`, strange because I have rights (on Huawei U8950-1 with the same rights I can do this):

`drwxr-xr-x root     root              2014-09-04 10:26 dev`

Looks like approach described below work not for all android devices. Can someone explain why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is already a fix in this libusb fork:

https://github.com/martinmarinov/rtl_tcp_andro-

Now, not only you will need to pass the file descriptor, you will need to pass the device file path as well via UsbDevice.getDeviceName().

Comment: Thanks for response, but I preferred https://github.com/Gritzman/libusb because Gritzman's solutions has been implemented without modifying `libusb.h`

Comment: @CAMOBAP I'm trying to use Gritzman's version of libusb. How do I pass in the file descriptor? How do I get a libusb_device for the libusb_open() first parameter? Thanks.

Comment: @AntaoAlmada look at https://github.com/Gritzman/libusb/blob/master/jni/usb/os/linux_usbfs.c (comments with Android). There is no need to modify interface and pass file descriptior

Answer (score 2):

Looks like `Android L` have an additional restriction about accessing to `/dev` deirectory. I have no more ideas about this

**Update**

[Security Enhancements in Android 5.0](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/security/enhancements/enhancements50.html)

> ...
>
> Android sandbox reinforced with [SELinux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security-Enhanced_Linux). Android now requires [SELinux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security-Enhanced_Linux) in enforcing mode for all domains. [SELinux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security-Enhanced_Linux) is a [mandatory access control (MAC) system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandatory_access_control) in the Linux kernel used to augment the existing [discretionary access control (DAC) security] model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discretionary_access_control). This new layer provides additional protection against potential security vulnerabilities.
>
> ...

**Workarounds**

1. Install [SELinuxModeChanger](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mrbimc.selinux) and change SELinux mode to `permissive`
2. https://github.com/Gritzman/libusb

Answer (score 0):

There is a custom libusb 1.0 which is capable of solving this issue by doing LibusbInit by passing the path of the usb device , this can bypass readdir command http://www.libusb.org/ download from the home webpage itself.

Comment: direct link to the commit/issue please?