# Android L 5.0 & libusb 1.0.9 - no permissions?

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, libusb

I currently have an Android application connecting to a device via USB OTG.
The communication is done using the libusb 1.0.9 and it's working pretty well for other devices with api level < 21.
(The communication must be native due to performance issues)
When running the app under Android L, I get the following error from libusb_init(NULL):

```
type=1400 audit(0.0:107): avc: denied { read } for name="usb" dev="tmpfs" ino=24433 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0 tcontext=u: object_r:usb_device:s0 tclass=dir
A/libc(12605): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x0 in tid 12605 (mapp.sdk.sample)
```

I'm compiling libusb 1.0.9 using latest NDK 10c on my Nexus 5.
I don't think it's ART runtime issue as the app works on Android 4.4.4 with ART enabled instead of Dalvik.
Anyone familiar with this issue? ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25662307/android-libusb-init-returns-libusb-error-other-99/26034824#26034824) looks similar )
Can this be related to PIE?

Thank you.

Comment: "I think it's ART" -- should it be "I **don't** think it's ART..."?

Comment: Looks like selinux is denying you.

Comment: Thanks Dan.
Installing "SELinuxModeChanger" on my nexus 5 and changing the SELinux mode to Permissive seems to fix the problem.
The question is how to make my app work under the default Enforcing mode.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android L | libusb\_init returns LIBUSB\_ERROR\_OTHER (-99)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25662307/android-l-libusb-init-returns-libusb-error-other-99)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I uploaded a solution that works.
it's based on libusb 1.0.9 and working with Lollipop.

https://github.com/Gritzman/libusb

Comment: Thanks! This fixed the permissions issue.